# How to print the Unicode character 0254 (reverse c) in XeLaTeX

Tags: unicode, xelatex

If I write "\char"0254" in the source file XeLaTeX produces a space instead of reverse c. Reverse c stands for the sound "aw" as in "claw". I am running XeLaTeX in Windows 10. It is reputed to print Unicode characters so I would have thought it would print this one. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: `\Elzopeno` maybe?

Comment: Interesting, but Xelatex does not accept it.